# Usages of word Would

Tags: verb-forms, future-in-past

I have some problem to understand the true usage of “would”. I have already reviewed many forums and websites, but I have not managed to come to any conclusion upon which it can cover all cases I am facing with the usage of "would". As I have got so far, the “would” can be used in these circumstances:

1. “Past Habits”: When I were child, I would play soccer a lot.
2. “Past refusal”: I asked him for help, but he wouldn’t.
3. “with Wish”: I wish she would leave
4. “Conditional”: If he were here, I would ask him.
5. “Future in past”: I knew it would rain.
6. “Politeness marker”: I’d like a coffee please.

But still there are some sentences I cannot figure out why "would" has been used.

1. How much **would** a taxi cost to travel 50 miles? It **would** cost you $99.
2. Small flourishing companies **would be harmed** by increase in the minimum wage.
3. No man alive **would believe** it.

From those 6 types of “would” aforementioned, which type are these ones?

Comment: I find it interesting that the only use of *would* you haven't figured out is its most common, default one. While your use number one is pretty much the last one a native speaker is likely to learn. Peculiar.

Comment: And would you please tell me what that most common one is which is missing in that list? What do you mean by default?

Answer (score 4):

1 and 2 are both conditional uses, although the condition is implicit rather than expressly stated:

> [If I took a taxi], how much would it cost to travel 50 miles?
>
> [If the minimum wage were increased], small flourishing companies would be harmed.

3 could be either a conditional or a 'future in past', depending on context:

> [If I claimed that the moon is only five miles above the earth] **no man alive would believe it**.
>
> [Lady Mary had in fact been shown the principle underlying vaccination in Turkey in 1718], but **no man alive would believe it**. It was not until Jenner's work in the 1790s that vaccination was adopted by the medical profession.

Comment: A modal answer.

Comment: When I hear someone knocking on the door, my mom say to me, "That would be StoneyA." What would be the implict condition here? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng: That's an inferential use of *will/would*, not a conditional use.

Comment: As regards this inferential usage, can I say that "would" is a less certain version of "will" just as is the case for "might" with "may"? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng It *might* be, but in practice they are virtually identical.

Comment: When "would have +pp" is used in this inferential way, is it the same as "will have +pp"? I guess that "would have" refers to a finished event and "will have" refers to a state originated from a past event. Am I right? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Usually they're equivalent: present inferences concerning a past event. "Somebody washed the dishes." "Oh, that *will/would* have been Kevin; he likes to keep things tidy."

Comment: MacMillan says would can be used when you think someone is willing to do something. An example is given: Bruce would lend you the money, I'm sure. And I think that's an inferential use and MacMillan overreaches here. Am I right? Does **would** have the meaning of "be willing to" here? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I think MacMillan's got it right.

Comment: I would think the underlying logic is **"would = would be willing to"**, isn't it? If so, the example = Bruce would be willing to lend you the money[if you asked him.] @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I think you're looking for more 'logic' than is there.

Comment: Huh. I upvoted this first time round, and it still won't let me do it again.

Answer (score 0):

One use of would that I can't properly explain is: I really wouldn't know.
I guess it is an elliptical conditional sentence. But how to fomulate the full sentence so that it contains all the words of the shortened formula?

Comment: It's a hedging usage, less abrupt than 'I don't know!' and certainly than 'Why on earth should I be expected to know?!'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Nice explanation!  Would the following formula be possible? I wouldn't know how I could answer your question, even if my life depended on it. (A conditional sentence with the words: wouldn't and know). Perhaps there is something shorter.

Comment: Once you have the how-clause, followed by the if-clause, the modal must be interpreted as forming a conditional. It's not the hedging usage.

Answer (score -3):

What is **would**? Its second or what we call, past tense of **Will**. But still note that there is no such thing as past tense of **will** it's just being used to use it.

You have some errors in your text, too. Sorry I am editing them!

1. When I were child, I would play soccer a lot. Its wrong. The correct thing is: When I were a child, I played soccer a lot. Showing that when I was a child, I loved to play soccer! No would here. Would have been used to tell that I wish I was able to play soccer. You're wrong in example! Or you **would** have used When I were a child, I would have loved to play soccer a lot.
2. I wish she would leave. Well this is just a wish, that she might leave!
3. If he were here, I would ask him. The correct is: If he was here, I would have asked him.
4. I’d like a coffee please. Hey bud, you're asking about **would**. **Wouldn't** there be **would** instead of had ('d) like this: I would like a cup of coffee please.

As I said: would is second or past tense of will. When you use **would** you mean to say that something happened in past. Like **No man alive would believe it.** In this, you're telling the person, that if you go and tell people about something they won't believe it.

There is another example: Small flourishing companies would be harmed by increase in the minimum wage. In this one you're trying to tell the second person that it will be a negative effect on the average companies if you **will** increase the wages.

Using **will** is meant for the purposes that are going to happen in near future or far future or what so ever. But **would** is meant to give a past effect to it!

**Answer to your question:**

And for your question, the first example is more like a question form. I am not sure about the first one, its a condition but at the same time a question and answer. So there is no choice for it in those 6! Sorry.

Second one is condition, you're giving a condition that "This would happen to them if you do this".

Third one is future in past. "When you tell them, no one believes you about this".